# How to create xml start and end tag for empty tag without any space using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

creating duplicate tag for empty tag without any space using xslt.
 for example request as in code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Name>PJ</Name>
    <address/>
    <param/>
</root>
```

Output as :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Name>PJ</Name>
    <address></address>
    <param></param>
</root>
```

Comment: Client is using old system and they need it in this format.

Comment: I don't know of a good way to do this. Ostensibly, you could set the output method to HTML - but then your processor will most likely not close the <param> tag at all. The "bad" way would output the tags as text, and I can't really recommend doing that.

Comment: @roushan And that's your lesson why it *never* is appropriate to parse XML with anything other than an XML parser. Your client made that mistake and now you have to work around their stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I can't really recommend this, but if all else fails try including the following template in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(* or text())]">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', $name, '&gt;&lt;/', $name, '&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this does not copy namespaces or attributes.

Comment: This gives the output as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>PJ
<address></address>
<param></param> but here am missing the fields which are having values

Comment: Well, of course you are: you need to **add** this to your existing stylesheet (which you haven't showed us).

Comment: am creating a new xslt as u said:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(* or text())]">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', $name, '&gt;&lt;/', $name, '&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text() | processing-instruction() | comment()">
<xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. I thought you already had an a stylesheet. If you don't, then create one and include the [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) and the template above.

Answer (score 1):

Let your XSLT do its thing, don't try to bend it<sup>(1)</sup>.

Take the XML file it produces and regex-replace<sup>(2)</sup>: `<([^/\s]+)\s*/>` with `<\1></\1>`.

---

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Trying to bend it will only produce extremely ugly XSLT for no good reason.</sub>

<sub><sup>(2)</sup> Make sure you open and save the XML file in the encoding that it's in, in your case `UTF-8`.</sub>

Comment: I didnt understood your replace function. can u plz elaborate it.

Comment: Take a programming/scripting language of your choice, write a three line script that opens the XML file as text, does a regular expression search-and-replace operation and saves it again. Alternatively extend the program that runs the XSLT transformation. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: @roushan As an aside, please don't use chat speak like "u plz" on StackOverflow. We have enough time to spell out the words properly here.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<!-- <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name()"/> -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', local-name(), '&gt;&lt;/', local-name(), '&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text() | processing-instruction() | comment()">
<xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```